# Uncountable number of mutually disjoint countable sets in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist countable/uncountable number of mutually disjoint subsets of $\mathbb R$, each of which is countable and dense in $\mathbb R$?

For finite number, I am able to choose irrationals say, $r_n=\sqrt2-\frac1n$, and get the finite number of mutually disjoint sets as the rationals in $s_1=(-\infty,r_1),s_2=(r_1,r_2),\dots$ But how is such a thing possible for countable/uncountable irrationals because they can not be arranged in increasing order? Is there any other way of doing this? Is the answer to this question in the affirmative? Please help.

Comment: Cosets of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an uncountable set of countable dense sets.  Define an equivalence relation on the reals as $x\sim y \iff x-y \in \Bbb Q.\ \ $  Each equivalence class is countable, so there is an uncountable number of them.  They are disjoint and dense.

Comment: For uncountable collection the arguments are perfectly true but how do I do for countable and finite cases? I realize that my argument for finite case is wrong since the sets s1,s2,.... are not dense in R. Please help.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking about a finite number.  Do you just want a finite collection of dense sets?  Pick some irrationals like $\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3$ and you can have three sets, the rationals, the rationals plus $\sqrt 2$ and the rationals plus $\sqrt 3$.  For a countable collection take the rationals plus the square roots of each prime.

Comment: I get the answer I am looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: One more doubt. Is Q+sqrt(2) dense in R? I have learned that Z[sqrt(2)] is dense in R.

Comment: Yes.  Given $x \in \Bbb R$ you can find a member of $\Bbb Q$ that is close to $x-\sqrt 2$.  The fact that $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ is dense is different.

Comment: @RossMillikan while calculating zero equivalence class it has  the elements of $\mathbb{R}$ then it is not countable.?

Comment: @RossMillikan ,thank you for your response, i have one more doudt, if we consider the equivalence class of any rational number  then it also uncountable, then how can we say that each equivalence class is countable?

Comment: @Grvsaini:  Sorry, my last was wrong.  The equivalence classes are each countable.  The equivalence class of $0$ is all the rational numbers.  The equivalence class of $\sqrt 2$ is all numbers of the form $\sqrt 2 + rational$.  Each of these is countable.

Answer (score 1):

The construction that yields [Vitali sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) answers your question in the affirmative. The subsets are the elements of $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$, each of which is a shifted $\mathbb Q$, which in turn is countable and dense.