# Existence of mutually disjoint subsets of $\Bbb R$ which are countable and dense in $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

Which of the following statements are true?

1. There exists three mutually disjoint subsets of $\Bbb R$, each of which is countable and dense in $\Bbb R$
2. For each $n \in \Bbb N$, there exists $n$ mutually disjoint subsets of $\Bbb R$, each of which is countable and dense in $\Bbb R$
3. There exist countably infinite number of mutually disjoint subsets of $\Bbb R$, each of which is countable and dense in $\Bbb R$
4. There exist uncountable number of mutually disjoint subsets of $\Bbb R$, each of which is countable and dense in $\Bbb R$

We know that

1. $A$ is countable if $A$ ~ $\Bbb N$
2. $A$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ if $\bar A = \Bbb R$

I think if option 4 is correct then all options are correct.

If I take $A = \Bbb Q$ and $B = \Bbb Q -({a})$ such that $\bar A = \Bbb R$ and
$\bar B = \Bbb R$ but $ A \cap B \neq \phi$

How can we get $A$ and $B$ such that $\bar A = \Bbb R$ and $\bar B = \Bbb R$ with $ A \cap B = \phi$

Comment: For your question in the last line take $A=\mathbb  Q, B=\mathbb  R \setminus \mathbb  Q$

Comment: There is already a question about that: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501644/uncountable-number-of-mutually-disjoint-countable-sets-in-mathbb-r

Answer (score 1):

Take any basis $\cal B$ of $\Bbb R$ considered as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$. Then the sets $\Bbb Q b$ with $b\in \cal B$ are dense in $\Bbb R$ and pairwise disjoint. Moreover there are uncountable many of these sets.